# Degree of a Vandermonde Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, determinant

Show that f(t) has degree n. Find the coefficient of k of $t^n$ using the formula from n-1 case.
$$f(t)= det
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\\\
a_0 & a_1 & \cdots & t \\\\
a_0^2 & a_1^2 & \cdots & t^2 \\\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots\\\\
a_0^n & a_1^n & \cdots & t^n \\\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
How do I show the degree being equal to n? It seems like it just should be; however, I have no idea how to show this. 
The formula referred to in the second question is 
$$det(a)=\Pi_{i>j}(a_i-a_j)$$
I do not know how to apply this to the n-1 case.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the determinant of a square matrix by expanding along a row or column?

Answer (score 1):

To see that the degree if $n$, expand along the last column using [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion). Note that the other columns are independent of $t$.

The coefficient is $(-1)^{n+n}\det(a)$

Comment: $(-1)^{n+n}$ being a complicated way of writing $1$.

Comment: yup, but i was hoping that he can see that it is part of the Laplace expansion.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh When I am doing the cofactor expansion along the last column I get end up with $\sum_{n=1;k}(-1)^{n-1}t^n*det(cofactor matrix)$. How does this help to show that the degree is n? I guess I just don't understand.

Comment: what is $k$ in your term? Recall the definition of degree, it is the highest power that $t$ can take. You might like to work with explicit example to help your understanding